# Retrieving values through address in assembly

Tags: windows, assembly, nasm

We're trying to retrieve the value of first and second address but it's returning garbage. Please help.

---

Here's our code:

```
global _main
extern _printf, _system, _scanf, _gets, _getchar

section .text           ; Code section

_main:
; clear screen
    push clr
    call _system
    add esp, 4

;push dword [i]
;push prompt
;call _printf      
;add esp, 8

;MOV EAX, 0001
;MOV dword [i+EAX], 0002
;push dword [i+EAX]
;push prompt
;call _printf      
;add esp, 8

MOV EAX, 0001
MOV EBX, 0003
ARPLUS:
    ;FIRST
    MOV dword [i+EAX], EBX
    push dword [i+EAX]
    push prompt
    call _printf      
    add esp, 8
    ADD EAX, 0008
    INC EBX

    ;SECOND
    MOV dword [i+EAX], EBX
    push dword [i+EAX]
    push prompt
    call _printf      
    add esp, 8
    ADD EAX, 0008
    INC EBX

    ;THIRD
    MOV dword [i+EAX], EBX
    push dword [i+EAX]
    push prompt
    call _printf      
    add esp, 8
    ;INC EAX
    ;INC EBX

    ;RETRIEVE FIRST
    ADD EAX, 0008
    ;MOV dword [i+EAX], EBX
    push dword [i+EAX]
    push prompt
    call _printf      
    add esp, 8
    ;INC EAX
    ;INC EBX

    ;RETRIEVE SECOND
    ADD EAX, 000F
    ;MOV dword [i+EAX], EBX
    push dword [i+EAX]
    push prompt
    call _printf      
    add esp, 8

    ret

section .data
clr         db "cls",0
prompt  db "The number you entered is %d",13,10,0         
i       dd 0
```

<------------------------------------------->

UPDATE 2
Thanks Peter Cordes for your wonderful suggestion!

To answer some of your questions, here's the objective of the code we are tasked to do:

Facilitate an array code to store n count of numbers. Meaning, we need to play with memory spaces and allocations to store numbers and values.
As a sample, we tried to store the numbers 3, 4, 5 to contiguous memory heaps/spaces.
To test reliability and data authenticity, we tried to store 3, 4, 5 into what we supposed to be contiguous memory heaps and tried to "reprint" or "revisit" values by reaccessing memory spaces and printing their values. But we had no success.
As such, based on your suggestion, I tried to redo it, but: It did not produce the same results. It did not store values 3, 4, 5 (or 3, at least), and reprint these values to prove that they were stored in the memory.

I have remodeled your code suggestion to make it loop but it just loops indefinitely.

```
global _main
extern _printf, _system, 

section .text           ; Code section

_main:
; clear screen
    push clr
    call _system
    add esp, 4


MOV EAX, 0001
MOV EBX, 0003
MOV ECX, 0004     ; Counter for looping conditions

        AGAIN:
        push ebx

        MOV EBX, [i]    ; where does storing of 3, 4, 5 begin?
        push ebx
        push prompt
        call _printf

        add ebx, 8
        mov [esp+4], ebx
        mov dword [esp], prompt
        call _printf
        DEC ECX             ; ECX is the counter to check loop conditions
        CMP ECX, 0000       ; ECX is checked if it's still non negative
        JGE AGAIN           ; If it is, then "AGAIN" is re-performed
        JMP LAST            ; If not, then it will end the code. 


    LAST:
        add esp, 8
        pop ebx
        ret

    ret

section .data
clr         db "cls",0
prompt  db "Value is %d",13,10,0         
i       dd 0
```

Sorry, I'm a total newbie to the assembly language. What's wrong with my loop? Why is it running indefinitely? The logic I tried to do is:

Counter is ECX, which dictates the looping condition (as dictated by ECX)
Upon reaching printf, ECX gets decremented. CMP checks if ECX is not yet a negative and returns to "AGAIN".
But it loops indefinitely. I hope you don't mind, but please comment possible corrections on my code (in full) whenever possible. Sorry, I am a total novice in Assembly language.

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: re:edit: Now you're pushing ebx inside the loop (after you've already destroyed the caller's data in ebx outside the loop).  Only one call to printf should be inside the loop: the one that uses mov instead of push.  You need to use a debugger and see what your code does.  There's a lot of stuff wrong, and you'll learn more from finding it yourself.  Also, you still aren't doing anything with an array here.  It wasn't clear what you were even trying to do the first time, and my answer was based on the guess that you wanted to print 0, 8, 16, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to retrieve "the value of the address", like you say in the text?  (i.e. the numerical value of the pointer itself).  You're doing that with `push prompt`, to push a pointer to the format string.

Or do you want the value **at** the address?  i.e. dereference the pointer / label.  You're doing that with `push [i]`.

You're loading garbage from beyond `i` in the data section when you load from `[i+eax]`, where eax is non-zero.

If you want to print i, then i+8, then i+16, do something like:

```
push  ebx

mov   ebx, [i]     ; ebx is call-preserved, so we can keep a var live in a reg across calls
push  ebx
push  prompt
call  _printf
; add esp, 0x8     ; instead of popping, reuse the space: 

; at this point, eax = return value of printf, i.e. number of chars printed.
; adding to it and using it as an array index for i was your problem.

add  ebx, 8
mov  [esp+4], ebx
mov  [esp], prompt ; called functions "own" their args, and may have clobbered, so re-do the store.  But with mov instead of push, because the stack pointer is already offset
call _printf

; put this in a loop with a cmp ebx, something / jle instead of fully unrolling it.


add   esp, 8  ; *now* pop the args, after all the calls.

pop   ebx     ; restore ebx, which we pushed at the start because *we're* not allowed to modify it.  Our caller might break otherwise.
ret
```

See the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) wiki for links to the NASM manual, and the Intel insn ref manual, and much other stuff.

Comment: Hi, Mr. Peter, We have updated this question to answer your questions. Please check. Thank you very much!